# Aggregate return empty array with custom variable

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is a link to understand the structure : https://mongoplayground.net/p/TUsBjiboKLk

I'm basically looking for the communities that the user is following which work just fine in mongoplayground.

But replacing the "userId1" with a custom javascript variable is not working.

```
pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            userId: "userId1", // <================
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$userId",
                "$$userId"
              ],
              
            },
            
          },
          
        },
        
      ],
```

```
pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            userId: myCustomVarible, // <================
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$userId",
                "$$userId"
              ],
              
            },
            
          },
          
        },
        
      ],
```

Here is the full code for further explanation:

```
app.get("/communities/following", (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.query.userId;
    Community.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "follows",
                    localField: "communityId",
                    foreignField: "communityId",
                    as: "follows",
                },
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$follows",
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "users",
                    let: {
                        userId: "$follows.userId",
                    },
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                userId: userId,
                                $expr: {
                                    $eq: ["$userId", "$$userId"],
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    as: "users",
                },
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$users",
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    name: 1,
                    avatar: 1,
                },
            },
        ],
        (err, data) => {
            if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
            else res.status(201).send(data);
        }
    );
});
```

If i replace `const userId = req.query.userId;` width `const userId = "myUserId";` it's working

Comment: What is the type of `userId` string or ObjectId?

Comment: Strange! is value coming for `myCustomVarible` did you try to console.log it? If you hard code the value is the query is it working from the code?

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar `userId` is a string

Comment: hard codding the value coming from `myCustomVariable` is working fine too.

Comment: Can you `console.log(myCustomVariable)` where it's not working, what do you get ?

Comment: To give more details, i'm getting the userId from a query 

`app.get("/communities/following", (req, res) => {
    const myCustomVariable = req.query.userId;
    Community.aggregate(.......)
});`
console logging myCustomVariable return the userId just fine, but using this inside the aggregate is no working. BUT if i set 
const myCustomVariable = "userId1" it is working. Is this because i'm getting my res data too late ?

Comment: Can you please add your full code to the question?

Comment: Done, it might be easier with the full code yes..

Comment: can you `console.log(req.query.userId)` what do you get ?

Comment: I'm getting "7arvEbQx3wVggqabwdOionRsPBz1" which is my userId. And if i replace `const userId = req.query.userId;` with `const userId = "7arvEbQx3wVggqabwdOionRsPBz1"` i'm getting my data ...

Comment: Ok console.log actually give me the hint. I found the solution. Thanks for your time ! I posted the answer

Comment: Glad you found it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the problem, i was testing this using :

`http://localhost:9000/communities/following?userId="7arvEbQx3wVttqnbwmOionRsPBz1"`

where it should be without the quotes

`http://localhost:9000/communities/following?userId=7arvEbQx3wVttqnbwmOionRsPBz1`